# "Unit.UnitTestAdapter could not be loaded"

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS Ultimate and getting error.

> The test adapter (`'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`) required to execute this test could not be loaded. Check that the test adapter is installed properly. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

where can I find `UnitTestAdapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be because the DLL is getting picked from the wrong location. See the path for the DLL. If it's getting picked from the folder "Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" then pick it up from the corresponding "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" folder instead.